# Deleted Windows boot partition by mistake

Tags: boot, partitioning, mbr

I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop. Today, while trying to manually partition the drive for Linux install, I accidentally formatted the 100 MB System Reserved partition to ext4. Then, I ignored the problem and went on with installing Linux on my intended partitions.
 By the way, I used to use the Windows boot loader to dual boot (edited with EasyBCD).
Is it possible to fix this problem using the Windows 7 Setup CD and then configure the dual boot using EasyBCD like I used to do?

Answer (score 1):

For repair the Windows boot, you must start from the Windows 7 DVD, choose language, select "repair your computer", then you must select the Windows installation, click "next" and select "Command Prompt". Here, you must writte the followings commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
exit
```

And restart.

With this, the system will start on Windows. I don't know about EasyBCD and if you can set up a dual boot. But in any case, after this you can repair the grub of your linux installation and it will show you both system with no problem.

Comment: that gets the job done for Windows 7 as well as 8